# How to reload dataTable after deleting records/data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I have generated records and each row has delete button, And when I click delete button it will delete the records from the db. Also, after delete it will reload dataTable. Any Help for this?

DataTables:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({

    "processing": true,

     //some settings?
});
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="delete-product-"]', function() {

    var id = this.id.split('-').pop();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'my_controller/delete_product',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(callback)
        {
            //What should I code here, that can't reload entire page, only the table 
            //after deleting records
        },
        error: function(status)
        {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have to reload whole table data, just remove the deleted row.

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="delete-product-"]', function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var id = this.id.split('-').pop();
    var table = $('#table_id_selector').DataTable(); // replace with your table id 
    selector
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'my_controller/delete_product',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(callback)
        {
            table.row( $button.parents('tr') ).remove().draw();
        },
        error: function(status)
        {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great. It's Working now, Thank You So much Bro,

Comment: follow up question bro, about EDIT? should reload whole page? or can you give me some idea?

Comment: @MarkyOnyab great. appreciate if you accept my answer by putting a green tick next to it. about editing, it's a bir more than deleting. simple input boxes can be done by replacing each table cell with a textbox then replace them back to text after update is done. but complex input types like datepickers, dropdowns, rich text fields that you better not display in the table, you'll need a seperate page for editing. if you'll need some detailed editing in the future i suggest seperate page. but if you need speed like editing multiple records but tiny changes then you need to do it in the table.

Comment: at the begining of my answer, on the left click the empty tick to make it green

Comment: about this one sir @Ergec http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628994/shorthand-for-ajax-code

Comment: pass a false parameter table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false ); This will redraw the table keeping the current paging