# Shorthand for ajax code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was thinking that code is ugly, because it's too long and I was wondering that there is a shorthand for this. I Need Help!

In my View:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php foreach($products as $key => $value) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="data-id"><?php echo $value->prod_id; ?></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="data-prodname-<?php echo $value->prod_id; ?>"><?php echo $value->product_name; ?></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            &#8369; <span id="data-price-<?php echo $value->prod_id; ?>"><?php echo $value->price; ?></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-edit" id="edit-product-<?php echo $value->prod_id; ?>">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

After click edit button, jQuery will trigger. And I see my jquery it has very long code, I just replace the html code, And I think it has shorthand for this. Anyone can help me? Thank you in Advance.

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
type: 'post',
url: 'Jewelry_controller/edit_product_exe',
dataType: 'json',
data: dataString,
success: function(callback)
{
    var a;
    var productContainer = '<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover table-striped">';
        productContainer += '<tr>';
        productContainer += '<th>ID</th>';
        productContainer += '<th>Product Name</th>';
        productContainer += '<th>Price</th>';
        productContainer += '<th>Action</th>';
        productContainer += '</tr>';

        for(var i = 0; i < callback.length; i++)
        {
            a = callback[i];
            var ternary = a.status == '1' ? "Active" : "Inactive";

            productContainer += '<tr>';
            productContainer += '<td><span id="data-id">' + a.id +'</span></td>';
            productContainer += '<td><span id="data-prodname-'+ a.id +'">' + a.product_name + '</span></td>';
            productContainer += '<td>&#8369<span id="data-price-'+ a.id +'">' + a.price + '</span></td>';
            productContainer += '<td>';
            productContainer += '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal" id="edit-product-' + a.id + '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>';
            productContainer += '</td>';
            productContainer += '</tr>';
        }

    productContainer += '</table>';

    $('#table-product').html(productContainer);
}
});
```

In success code, it has very long long long code. I want to make it short, anyone can help? Thank you in Advance
I'm new in AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

For ajax post:
visit https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

For creating custom html markup with jquery.

```
     $('<div/>', {
       'id':'myDiv1',
        'class':'myClass',
         'style':'cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;',
         'html':'<span>Creating dynamic content</span>',
         'click':function(){ alert(this.id) },
         'mouseenter':function(){ $(this).css('color', 'red'); },
          'mouseleave':function(){ $(this).css('color', 'black'); }
         }).appendTo('#myDiv2');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to put your "html-in-javascript" into HTML. It looks like (it's not working code, only idea)

HTML

```
<template id="products-tpl">
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="data-id"><%=data[i].id %></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="data-prodname-<%=data[i].id %>"><%=data[i].product_name %></span>
            </td>
            <td>&#8369<span id="data-price-<%=data[i].id %>"><%=data[i].price %></span></td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal" id="edit-product-<%=data[i].id %>">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Javasript

```
$('#table-product').html(template("products-tpl", callback));
```

You can choose one of template-frameworks here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript_templates

Comment: Example without ajax, for main templating idea https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/rmzndbss/1/