# Error in Refreshing Datatable Using AJAX in Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

First sorry for my bad english.
I am trying to create button in my datatable. The button for delete data in that row. Delete function works. The problem is after the delete, my Datatable did not refresh the content (Only when I refresh the page, the content refreshed).

I already try some suggestion in other's stackoverflow. 
My datatble id = "data'
var data as global variable.

This is my JavaScript Code (inside document.ready) :

```
    var temp = $('#data').DataTable
({
  "columns":
  [
    null, null, null, null,
    null, null, null,
    {"width": "17%"}
  ]
});

table = JSON.parse('"' + temp + '"');
```

This is my code for button function

```
   function delete(kode) {

var x =  confirm("Do you want to delete this data?");

if (x == true)
{
  jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "***"
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function()
     {
      table.ajax.reload();
      alert("delete success");
     },
    error : function()
     {
       table.ajax.reload();
       alert("delete fail");
     }
  });
} }
```

Error in console :

> Uncaught Type-error: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
>       at Object.error (hotel:191)
>       at u (VM226 jquery.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (VM226 jquery.js:2)
>       at k (VM226 jquery.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (VM226 jquery.js:2)

Comment: *"Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined"* - Where do you define a variable called `table`?  Your DataTables instance is called `temp`.  You also may not need to reload the whole set of data, just delete that one record from the data.  And you probably don't need to reload or modify the table at all in the `error` callback, since the delete operation failed.

Comment: Table is global variable. my bad, in my post, it should not data = JSON.parse('"' + temp + '"'); but it should be Table = JSON.parse('"' + temp + '"');

Comment: when i remared the JSON.parse line. It gave me an alert "Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

Comment: when i remark the JSON.parse line. It gave me an alert "Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/1";  Of course I changed the variable temp to data when I tried it.

Comment: @David if I may know, why you said the delete opeartion failed? When I checked in my table in database (MySQL) , that row (data) deleted.

Comment: Well, if the AJAX operation is invoking the `error` callback then *something* server-side would have failed.  You may at least want to debug to confirm which callback is being invoked.  But reloading the entire table doesn't really seem necessary when you can just delete or not delete that one row from the table.  As for the error, your `table` variable is still never being populated with anything.  When you debug, what is in that variable?  What do you think should be in that variable?  Why?  (Basically, what are you expecting this to even do?: `table = JSON.parse('"' + temp + '"');`)

Comment: Please try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627166/how-to-reload-datatable-after-deleting-records-data

Comment: @SoravGarg thanks for the link. The status variable return a message : {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (e)
always
:
ƒ ()
catch
:
ƒ (e)
done
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (e)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (e)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
""
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (e,t)
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
200
statusCode
:
ƒ (e)
statusText
:
"OK"
then
:
ƒ (t,r,i)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: The ajax ifunction just to pass the data from view to controller right? Then do one / some action if success?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write below in ajax success. It will retrieve or refresh all the data of it.

```
var $lmTable = $("#data").dataTable({bRetrieve: true});
$lmTable.fnDraw();
```

Comment: TypeError: table.fnDraw is not a function
    at Object.error (hotel:243)
    at u (VM140 jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (VM140 jquery.js:2)
    at k (VM140 jquery.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM140 jquery.js:2)